# Working on an array method

Tags: ruby, arrays

In my homework, I had to create a digit_sum method for the Integer class. Outcome:

```
class Integer
    def digit_sum
        to_s.split("").inject(0) { |sum, n| sum + n.to_i }
    end
end
```

Now I have to create something similar for an Array:

```
[1, 2, 3, "words"].sum #=> 6
[12, 13, 14].sum_up_digit_sums #=> 12
```

But I don't know how to work with the Array Class. A simple start should look like that.

```
class Array
   def sum
       #Code
   end
end
```

An Array has variables and I don't know how to include those variables into my code. I hope someone can explain how I should work with this.

Comment: How `[12, 13, 14].sum_up_digit_sums` is giving `12`?

Comment: Hint: It's very similar to the code you already wrote for Integer, except you're working on an `Array` instance already, so for example, you could just send `inject`.

Comment: Why it `[1, 2, 3, "words"]` gives `7` ?

Comment: No, I could only guess.  Perhaps non-numbers are counted as 1?

Comment: @numbers1311407 [1, 2, 3, "words"] gives 6. That was my fault sry. You can check that out in ruby if you use .to_i on a String you get 0.

Comment: Whenever you have a choice between creating an array or an enumerator, you generally should opt for the latter, as it consumes less memory and is normally faster.  In your `digit_sum` method, for example, you might replace `split("")` with [String#each_char](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-each_char).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of `sum_up_digit_sums`

```
class Array
  def sum_up_digit_sums
    join.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
  end
end

puts [12, 13, 14].sum_up_digit_sums # => 12
```

Your `sum` requirements also satisfied with it.

Explanation for `[12, 13, 14]`:

1. `.join` will create a string from array given: `[12, 13, 14] => "121314"`
2. `.chars` will create an array of characters from this string `"121314" => ["1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "4"]`
3. `.map(&:to_i)` will call `to_i` on each character `["1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "4"] => [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]`(on this point, if you had any word characters, they'll become zeros)
4. Then simply sum everything with `.reduce(:+)`(`reduce` is an alias of `inject`)

Comment: Hmm, yeah this is the solution for what I had to do, but I don't see any code that tells ruby that I'm working with certain Array values. I don't really now how to put this into words. Let's have an Array    [1, 2, 3, "stack"] how does ruby know that I'm working with such values?

Comment: @CharlesNough I've added a step by step explanation

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the second one, a `Array#sum` method.  This is a commonly desired method and as such a practical homework question.

First, take a look at your existing implementation of `Integer#digit_sum`:

```
# Here you're taking a number, turning it into a string, and splitting it
# on an empty string, resulting in an array of characters (same effect as 
# `String#chars`)
to_s.split("").

# The result of this?  An array, to which you're then sending `inject` to 
# calculate the sum.  As you see you've already written a rudimentary 
# `Array#sum` (for ints) right here.
  inject(0) { |sum, n| sum + n.to_i }
```

Simply move that to an instance method of Array

```
class Array
  # whereas in your other method you send `inject` to an array you created, 
  # here you're sending it to *this* array instance `self`, which is the 
  # implicit target of instance methods. `self.inject` would be equivalent.
  def sum
    inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n.to_i }
  end
end
```

You could then use this to refactor your existing `Integer#digit_sum`

```
class Integer
  def digit_sum
    to_s.split("").sum
  end
end
```

Now take what you learned here to write the 2nd method.

```
class Array
  # There are plenty of ways to accomplish the task here, but for the sake
  # of pedagogy let's use the method you already wrote yourself.
  # This (rather fragile) method would assume you have an array of objects
  # that respond to `digit_sum`
  def sum_up_digit_sums
    # Exactly like plain `sum` but now we're using the other method you wrote,
    # `digit_sum` to determine the value instead of `to_i`
    inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n.digit_sum }
  end
end
```